# Docker, Nginx, localhost does not respond

Tags: php, docker, nginx, curl, docker-compose

I hope you're all doing well during this particular time.

I'm stuck on a problem concerning my nginx+php image, it's my first image I'm building from scratch (with Google), so I'm not sure everything is correct.

This image will serve me in multiple home projects, I'm using this image in a Gitlab Container Registry.

I'm using this Dockerfile :

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY --from=library/docker:latest /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/bin/docker
COPY --from=docker/compose:latest /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose


RUN adduser -S www-data -u 1000
RUN apk upgrade -U
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        git \
        bash \
        vim
RUN apk --update --no-cache add php7 php7-fpm php7-mysqli php7-json php7-openssl php7-curl \
    php7-zlib php7-xml php7-phar php7-intl php7-dom php7-xmlreader php7-ctype php7-session \
    php7-mbstring php7-gd nginx curl

RUN apk add --update --no-cache nginx supervisor

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN composer global require "hirak/prestissimo:^0.3" --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest --classmap-authoritative \
&& composer clear-cache
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.composer/vendor/bin"

COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN mkdir -p var/cache var/log var/sessions \
&& chown -R www-data var

VOLUME /srv/api/var
VOLUME /var/www/html
VOLUME /var/www/src

COPY index.php /var/www/html/

COPY src/run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod u+rwx /run.sh

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "/run.sh" ]
CMD ["init"]
```

Which calls this bash script, for Symfony migration:

```
#!/bin/bash

INIT=false
MIGRATION=false
CREATEDB=true

for DOCKER_OPTION in $@
do
    case "$DOCKER_OPTION" in
    init )
        INIT=true
        shift
        ;;
    migration )
        MIGRATION=true
        shift
        ;;
    with-existing-db )
        CREATEDB=false
        shift
        ;;
    * )
        break
        ;;
  esac
done

APP_ENV=${APP_ENV:-dev}

init_project () {
    composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest --no-interaction
    chmod +x bin/console && sync
    php bin/console assets:install

    if $CREATEDB
    then
        php bin/console doctrine:schema:update -f
        php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load -n
    fi
}

if $MIGRATION;
then
    php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction -vvv
    chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/api/var/
fi

if $INIT;
then
    mkdir -p /var/nginx/client_body_temp
    chown www-data:www-data /var/nginx/client_body_temp
    mkdir -p /var/run/php/
    chown www-data:www-data /var/run/php/
    touch /var/log/php-fpm.log
    chown www-data:www-data /var/log/php-fpm.log

    if [ "$APP_ENV" != 'prod' ];
    then
        init_project
    fi
    exec supervisord --nodaemon --configuration="/etc/supervisord.conf" --loglevel=info
fi

exec "$@";
```

Launched by this Docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  lamp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
      - ./src:/var/www/src/
```

With this Nginx configuration:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
error_log /dev/stdout;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    types {
        text/html                             html htm shtml;
        text/css                              css;
        text/xml                              xml;
        image/gif                             gif;
        image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
        application/javascript                js;
        application/atom+xml                  atom;
        application/rss+xml                   rss;
        image/svg+xml                         svg;
    }

    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_body;
    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;
    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;

    # mime types

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        access_log /dev/stdout;
        error_log /dev/stdout;

        location / {
                    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                    index index.html index.htm;
         }
    }

}
```

Everything seems to be going well.

Unfortunately I can't display my index.php (php_info).

When I do

> curl -vvv http://localhost:80

```
* Trying ::1:80...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

And When I do

> curl -vvv http://localhost:80 --trace-ascii dump.txt

```
== sync, corrected by elderman ==
== Info: Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 73 bytes (0x49)
0000: GET / HTTP/1.1
0010: Host: localhost
0021: User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
003a: Accept: */*
0047: 
== Info: Empty reply from server
== Info: Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I've searched the net, but my skills are quite limited in the configuration of nginx.

Do you have any ideas to submit to me.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?  (For example, do you have the same problem just running nginx without the detailed PHP configuration?  Does your application need packages like `vim` to run, or can they be omitted?)

Comment: Hi David, i replied with new answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61559239/12070178

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply,

For VIM, he's already add here :

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        git \
        bash \
        vim
```

So i try with this Dockerfile, whitout PHP/Composer (It's pretty minimalist?) :

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY --from=library/docker:latest /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/bin/docker
COPY --from=docker/compose:latest /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

RUN adduser -S www-data -u 1000
RUN apk upgrade -U
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
        git \
        bash \
        vim
RUN apk --update --no-cache add nginx curl

RUN apk add --update --no-cache nginx supervisor

COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN mkdir -p var/cache var/log var/sessions \
&& chown -R www-data var

VOLUME /srv/api/var
VOLUME /var/www/html
VOLUME /var/www/src

COPY index.php /var/www/html/

COPY src/run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod u+rwx /run.sh

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "/run.sh" ]
CMD ["init"]
```

For

> curl -vv http://localhost:80

```
*   Trying ::1:80...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
```

And for

> curl -vv http://localhost:80 --trace-ascii dump.txt

```
== Info:   Trying ::1:80...
== Info: Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 73 bytes (0x49)
0000: GET / HTTP/1.1
0010: Host: localhost
0021: User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
003a: Accept: */*
0047: 
== Info: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
== Info: Closing connection 0
```

What do you think ?